# Programmatically adding products to tags in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm currently working on a custom import script for Magento and now I want to add products to the Tags from the CSV file. I've used a snippet from another question here on StackOverflow, but for some reason it doesn't do what is expected.

```
function addTag($bundleProductId, $tagArray) {
    $tags = explode(',', $tagArray);
    array_walk($tags, 'trim_value');

    $customerId = NULL;
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $productId = $bundleProductId;

    $tagModel = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
    //$tagModel->loadByName($tagName); // if not using a loop
    foreach ($tags as $tagName) {
    $tagModel->unsetData()->loadByName($tagName); //if using a loop 

        if (!$tagModel->getId()) {
             $tagModel->setName($tagName)
                  ->setFirstCustomerId($customerId)
                  ->setFirstStoreId($storeId)
                  ->setStatus($tagModel->getPendingStatus())
                  ->save();
        }
   $relationStatus = $tagModel->saveRelation($productId, $customerId, $storeId);
    }
}
```

After the script has run, the Admin Panel shows the new tags with a "1" in the "Products" column, (as expected,) but when I edit the Tag nothing has been selected.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to find until to see full code. But anyway here I have include another bit of code that I have used it regularly and its working fine.

```
<?php

class Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_ProductTags extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product {


public function saveRow(array $importData) {
    $product = $this->getProductModel ();
    $product->setData ( array () );
    if ($stockItem = $product->getStockItem ()) {
        $stockItem->setData ( array () );
    }
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productId='';
    $productId = $product->getIdBySku($importData['sku']);  
    $tagNames = $importData['product_tags'];
    if (empty ( $importData ['sku'] )) {
        $message = Mage::helper ( 'catalog' )->__ ( 'Skip import row, required field "%s" not defined', 'sku' );
        Mage::throwException ( $message );
    }       
    if ( !$productId ) {
        $message = Mage::helper ( 'catalog' )->__ ( 'Skip import row, required field "%s" not Valid Sku', $importData['sku'] );
        Mage::throwException ( $message );
    }
    if(strlen($tagNames) && $productId) {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->load($productId);
            $productId =$product->getId();
        if(!$product->getId()){
           $message = Mage::helper ( 'catalog' )->__ ( 'Skip import row, required field "%s" not valid', 'sku' );
            Mage::throwException ( $message );
        } else {
            try {
              $customerId = NULL;
              $storeId = 1;
              $tagModel='';                 
              $counter = new Varien_Object(array(
                        "new" => 0,
                        "exist" => array(),
                        "success" => array(),
                        "recurrence" => array())
                        );                  
               $tagModel = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
               $tagRelationModel = Mage::getModel('tag/tag_relation');
               $tagNamesArr = $this->_cleanTags($this->_extractTags($tagNames));
               foreach ($tagNamesArr as $tagName) {
                    $tagModel->unsetData()
                            ->loadByName($tagName)
                            ->setName($tagName)
                            ->setFirstCustomerId($customerId)
                            ->setFirstStoreId($storeId)
                            ->setStatus(1)
                            ->save();

                    $tagRelationModel->unsetData()
                        ->setStoreId($storeId)
                        ->setProductId($productId)
                        ->setCustomerId($customerId)
                        ->setActive(Mage_Tag_Model_Tag_Relation::STATUS_ACTIVE)
                        ->setCreatedAt( $tagRelationModel->getResource()->formatDate(time()) );

                    if (!$tagModel->getId()) {  
                        $tagModel->setName($tagName)
                            ->setFirstCustomerId($customerId)
                            ->setFirstStoreId($storeId)
                            ->setStatus($tagModel->getPendingStatus())
                            ->save();
                        $relationStatus = $tagModel->saveRelation($productId, $customerId, $storeId);
                        $counter[$relationStatus][] = $tagName; 
                        $tagRelationModel->setTagId($tagModel->getId())->save();
                        $counter->setNew($counter->getNew() + 1);
                    }
                    else { 
                        $tagStatus = $tagModel->getStatus();
                        $tagRelationModel->setTagId($tagModel->getId());
                        $relationStatus = $tagModel->saveRelation($productId, $customerId,'');
                        $counter[$relationStatus][] = $tagName; 
                        switch($tagStatus) {
                            case $tagModel->getApprovedStatus(): 
                                if($this->_checkLinkBetweenTagProduct($tagRelationModel)) { 
                                    $relation = $this->_getLinkBetweenTagCustomerProduct($tagRelationModel, $tagModel);
                                    if ($relation->getId()) {
                                        if (!$relation->getActive()) {
                                            $tagRelationModel
                                                ->setId($relation->getId())
                                                ->save();
                                        }
                                    } 
                                    else { 
                                        $tagRelationModel->save();
                                    }                                       
                                    $counter->setExist(array_merge($counter->getExist(), array($tagName)));
                                } 
                                else { 
                                    $tagRelationModel->save(); 
                                    $counter->setSuccess(array_merge($counter->getSuccess(), array($tagName)));
                                }
                                break;
                            case $tagModel->getPendingStatus(): 
                                $relation = $this->_getLinkBetweenTagCustomerProduct($tagRelationModel, $tagModel);
                                if ($relation->getId()) {
                                    if (!$relation->getActive()) {
                                        $tagRelationModel
                                            ->setId($relation->getId())
                                            ->save();
                                    }
                                } 
                                else {
                                    $tagRelationModel->save();
                                }
                                $counter->setNew($counter->getNew() + 1);
                                break;
                            case $tagModel->getDisabledStatus():
                                if($this->_checkLinkBetweenTagCustomerProduct($tagRelationModel, $tagModel)) {
                                    $counter->setRecurrence(array_merge($counter->getRecurrence(), array($tagName)));
                                } 
                                else {
                                    $tagModel->setStatus($tagModel->getPendingStatus())->save();
                                    $tagRelationModel->save();
                                    $counter->setNew($counter->getNew() + 1);
                                }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
                $message='Unable to save tag(s).';
                Mage :: throwException( $e.$message );
            }
        }
    }               
    return true;
}

   protected function _getLinkBetweenTagCustomerProduct($tagRelationModel, $tagModel){
        return Mage::getModel('tag/tag_relation')->loadByTagCustomer(
            $tagRelationModel->getProductId(),
            $tagModel->getId(),
            $tagRelationModel->getCustomerId(),
            $tagRelationModel->getStoreId()
          );
    }

     protected function _checkLinkBetweenTagCustomerProduct($tagRelationModel, $tagModel){
        return (count($this->_getLinkBetweenTagCustomerProduct($tagRelationModel, $tagModel)
            ->getProductIds()) > 0);
    }   
    protected function _checkLinkBetweenTagProduct($tagRelationModel){      
        $customerId = $tagRelationModel->getCustomerId();
        $tagRelationModel->setCustomerId(null);
        $res = in_array($tagRelationModel->getProductId(), $tagRelationModel->getProductIds());
        $tagRelationModel->setCustomerId($customerId); 
        return $res;
    }
    protected function _cleanTags(array $tagNamesArr){
        foreach( $tagNamesArr as $key => $tagName ){
            $tagNamesArr[$key] = trim($tagNamesArr[$key], '\'');
            $tagNamesArr[$key] = trim($tagNamesArr[$key]);
            if( $tagNamesArr[$key] == '' ) {
                unset($tagNamesArr[$key]);
            }
        }
        return $tagNamesArr;
    }
    protected function _extractTags($tagNamesInString){
        return explode("\n", preg_replace("/(\'(.*?)\')|(\s+)/i", "$1\n", $tagNamesInString));
    }   
    protected function userCSVDataAsArray($data) {
        return explode ( ',', str_replace ( " ", "", $data ) );
    }
    protected function skusToIds($userData, $product) {
        $productIds = array ();
        foreach ( $this->userCSVDataAsArray ( $userData ) as $oneSku ) {
            if (($a_sku = ( int ) $product->getIdBySku ( $oneSku )) > 0) {
                parse_str ( "position=", $productIds [$a_sku] );
            }
        }
        return $productIds;
    }

//// Para importar categorias
    protected $_categoryCache = array ();
    protected function _addCategories($categories, $store) {
        $rootId = $store->getRootCategoryId ();
        if (! $rootId) {
            return array ();
        }
        $rootPath = '1/' . $rootId;
        if (empty ( $this->_categoryCache [$store->getId ()] )) {
            $collection = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/category' )->getCollection ()->setStore ( $store )->addAttributeToSelect ( 'name' );
            $collection->getSelect ()->where ( "path like '" . $rootPath . "/%'" );
            foreach ( $collection as $cat ) {
                $pathArr = explode ( '/', $cat->getPath () );
                $namePath = '';
                for($i = 2, $l = sizeof ( $pathArr ); $i < $l; $i ++) {
                    $name = $collection->getItemById ( $pathArr [$i] )->getName ();
                    $namePath .= (empty ( $namePath ) ? '' : '/') . trim ( $name );
                }
                $cat->setNamePath ( $namePath );
            }               
            $cache = array ();
            foreach ( $collection as $cat ) {
                $cache [strtolower ( $cat->getNamePath () )] = $cat;
                $cat->unsNamePath ();
            }
            $this->_categoryCache [$store->getId ()] = $cache;
        }
        $cache = & $this->_categoryCache [$store->getId ()];            
        $catIds = array ();
        foreach ( explode ( ',', $categories ) as $categoryPathStr ) {
            $categoryPathStr = preg_replace ( '#s*/s*#', '/', trim ( $categoryPathStr ) );
            if (! empty ( $cache [$categoryPathStr] )) {
                $catIds [] = $cache [$categoryPathStr]->getId ();
                continue;
            }
            $path = $rootPath;
            $namePath = '';
            foreach ( explode ( '/', $categoryPathStr ) as $catName ) {
                $namePath .= (empty ( $namePath ) ? '' : '/') . strtolower ( $catName );
                if (empty ( $cache [$namePath] )) {
                    $cat = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/category' )->setStoreId ( $store->getId () )->setPath ( $path )->setName ( $catName )->// comment out the following line if new categories should stay inactive
                    setIsActive ( 1 )->save ();
                    $cache [$namePath] = $cat;
                }
                $catId = $cache [$namePath]->getId ();
                $path .= '/' . $catId;
            }
            if ($catId) {
                $catIds [] = $catId;
            }
        }
        return join ( ',', $catIds );
    }
}
```

`

I download it few months ago from some where. Configure local module ( actually overwrite the core system ) place this file this location.app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Model\Convert\Adapter\ then,
Go to Admin section and go to  system->Import/Export/Advanced Profile 
    Click on Create New profile
    Give proile name as Product Tag Import
    and in Actions XML *  paste below code

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load"> 
                <var name="type">file</var> 
                <var name="path">var/import</var> 
                <var name="filename"><![CDATA[tag_file.csv]]></var> 
                <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var> 
            </action> 

            <action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse"> 
                <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var> 
                <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var> 
                <var name="fieldnames">true</var> 
                <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var> 
                <var name="number_of_records">1</var> 
                <var name="decimal_separator"><![CDATA[.]]></var> 
                <var name="adapter">catalog/convert_adapter_ProductTags</var> 
                <var name="method">parse</var> 
            </action>
```

tag_file.csv is the file of your import data. this file contains just 2 fields, sku and product_tags.
Add your product sku's and corresponding tags. and put that file in your var/import directory. you can view this file in admin section as I mentioned above. Thats it ..!! Let me know if have any problem.

Comment: I've been taught not to edit the Core of Magento, to prevent messing up the webshop as soon as the installation of Magento is updated. But thanks, I'll look through this code.